# Making variables visible inside Powershell workflow

Tags: powershell, imagemagick

I have five variables defined before a workflow that need to be available to the workflow, but I can't find out how to do it.

Putting the variables inside the workflow makes them visible, but that causes an issue with the CSV import that means extra properties are added to the object relating to the workflow that I don't want.

Code as follows:

```
$source = 'C:\Users\Koozer\a place\'
$rotateParams = 90, 90, 270
$cropParams = @(64, 64), (32, 0)

$images = Import-Csv "${source}images.csv"
$colNames = $images[0].psobject.properties.Name

Workflow StitchCropWorkflow {

    foreach -parallel ($imageSet in $images) {
        $magickRotParams = ''
        $n = 0

        foreach ($image in $colNames) {
            $magickRotParams += '`( '''+$source+$imageSet.($image)+''' -rotate '+$rotateParams[$n]+' `) '
            $n++
        }

        $finfo = [io.fileinfo]$imagePathSets[0]
        $command = 'magick '+$magickRotParams+' +append -crop '+$cropParams[0][0]+'x'+$cropParams[0][1]+'+'+$cropParams[1][0]+'+'+$cropParams[1][1]+' +repage '''+$finfo.DirectoryName+'\'+$finfo.BaseName+'_stitch_crop'+$finfo.Extension+''''
        echo $command
        Invoke-Expression $command
    }
}

StitchCropWorkflow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters to a workflow like you would do it for a function:

```
$source = 'C:\Users\Koozer\a place\'
$rotateParams = 90, 90, 270
$cropParams = @(64, 64), (32, 0)

$images = Import-Csv "${source}images.csv"
$colNames = $images[0].psobject.properties.Name

Workflow StitchCropWorkflow {
    param (
        $source,
        $rotateParams,
        $cropParams,
        $images,
        $colNames
    )

    # your code here
}

StitchCropWorkflow $source $rotateParams $cropParams $images $colNames
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define a variable in a script containing a workflow, to access the variable within the workflow the syntax is `$using:variable`

As an example, here is a powershell script containing a workflow with a single param.

```
param([string]$ComputerName)
 $VerbosePreference = "Continue"
workflow Start-Reboot {
    param($server)

        Write-Verbose "Input server is $server"

        InlineScript{
        New-Item -Path C:\Scripts\Logging\Start-Reboot-Single.log -ItemType File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
        }

            Sequence{

            InlineScript
            {
                Try
                {

    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $using:server -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='HealthService'" | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name PauseService | Out-Null

    $operatingSystem = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $using:server -ErrorAction stop
    $LastReboot = [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($operatingSystem.LastBootUpTime).ToString().Trim()

    Write-Verbose "Last reboot time for $using:server is $LastReboot"

    Write-Verbose "Here we restart $using:server, for testing no reboot is done"

    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $using:server -Wait -For Wmi -Force

    $OSRecheck = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $using:server -ErrorAction stop
    $CurrentReboot =  [Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($OSRecheck.LastBootUpTime).ToString().Trim()

    $props = [Ordered]@{
        Server=$using:server
        LastReboot=$LastReboot
        CurrentReboot=$CurrentReboot
        }

            } Catch {
                Write-Verbose "Oh no, problem with $using:server"
                $rnd = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 5
                Start-Sleep -Seconds $rnd
                $err = $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
                    $props = [Ordered]@{
                    Server=$using:server
                    LastReboot=$err
                    CurrentReboot=$null
                    }
                } Finally {

        $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props

        $random = Get-Random -Minimum 2 -Maximum 15

        Start-Sleep -Seconds $random

        Write-Output $object | Out-File -Append -FilePath C:\Scripts\Logging\Start-Reboot-Single.log
        }

            }#inline end

            }#sequence end

}#end workflow block
 Start-Reboot -server $ComputerName
```